Inconsistent errors Object Structure in React Hook Form when Using setError Body:
I've encountered an inconsistency in the structure of the errors object provided by React Hook Form's useForm. When validation errors are generated through the resolver, the errors object structure is as expected, with field names as keys. However, when errors are set manually using setError (e.g., to handle server-side validation errors), the structure changes to an array-like format with numerical keys.
This discrepancy makes it challenging to handle errors uniformly in the application.
Environment:

React Hook Form Version: 7.54.2
Resolver Used: zod

Steps to Reproduce:

Initialize a form using useForm and integrate zod as the resolver.

Submit the form to generate validation errors using zod.

Observe the structure of the errors object — it has field names as keys, e.g.:
{
    email: { message: "Invalid email format", type: "invalid_string" },
    firstName: { message: "first name must be at least 2 characters long", type: "too_small" }
}


Use the setError function to set errors (e.g., to handle server-side errors).

Observe that the structure of the errors object changes to:


{
    "0": {
        "type": "manual",
        "message": { "path": "email", "message": "Invalid email format" }
    },
    "1": {
        "type": "manual",
        "message": { "path": "firstName", "message": "first name must be at least 2 characters long" }
    }
}

Expected Behavior:
The structure of the errors object should remain consistent, regardless of whether errors are set manually using setError or generated through the resolver. Ideally, it should always use field names as keys for easy access, such as:
{
    email: { message: "Invalid email format", type: "manual" },
    firstName: { message: "first name must be at least 2 characters long", type: "manual" }
}

Question:
Is there a way to ensure consistent structure for the errors object? Am I missing any configuration or best practices to handle this discrepancy?

I realized that the issue was caused by setting the wrong values in setError. Instead of providing the correct field names as keys, I was using an incorrect structure. Once I fixed that, the errors object was consistent as expected. Thank you to everyone who viewed or considered helping!
